# Update redis cache setting on ruby on rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

I am trying to locate to set the Redis cache setting on the Ruby on Rails project, but I am not able to find the path to set it up.

As I was looking on /etc/redis/redis.conf but I don't see anything related to Ruby on rails to update.

Is there a path for ruby on rails where I need to update the local or external Redis cache endpoint need to be updated?

Comment: Are you trying to tell your Rails application where Redis is located on your computer so that the Rails application can use it ?

Comment: Yes, I'm looking for the same setting where do I define the Redis settings on Rails?

Answer (score 1):

You can create `config/redis.yml` like this :

```
development:
  url: redis://localhost:6379/
  db: 0
 
production:
  url: 
  db: 0

test: 
  url: redis://localhost:6379/
  db: 1
```

And then create an initializer `config/initializrs/redis.rb` like this

```
conf = Rails.application.config_for(:redis)
REDIS = Redis.new(conf)
```

Now in your Rails app, you can use :
`REDIS.set("today","monday")`

`REDIS.get("today")` will return "monday".

Also you can use `Rails.application.config_for(:redis)` to make a reference to your Redis config in any other intitializer